# android fragments edittext button focus

Tags: android, button, focus, android-fragments, android-edittext

being new to android app development, I encounter a problem regarding the interaction of android fragments, edittexts, focus and buttons.

I have one fragment activity with several tabs. Most tabs have one fragment each. But in one tab, I have a `ListFragment` and a fragment with edittexts and buttons, which I call edit fragment. When the user selects a list item, the content of the edit fragment is shown in the current tab. When trying to edit a text there, more precisely, when hitting a different key than the backspace key, the new char is not shown, but the first button below gets the focus. Why? And how can I avoid this behavior?

Earlier, I had a different activity for the edit fragment and the editing worked perfectly. But for other reasons and because it is recommended, I have only one activity now. Thank you for help!

The xml for project_details1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/projectDetails">
            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsButtons"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#656565"
                    android:padding="5dp">
                    <Button android:id="@+id/projectDetailsButton_save" 
                            android:text="@string/save"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2" />
                    <Button android:id="@+id/projectDetailsButton_cancel" 
                            android:text="@string/cancel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="2" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_above="@id/projectDetailsButtons">
            <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="15dip"
            android:background="@color/myColor"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/projectNo" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsProjectNr"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/projectNo"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </TextView>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/description" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsProjectDescription"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                     />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsClientName"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/customerNo" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsClientNr"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
             <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/bookingNo" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsBookingNr"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/orderNo" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/projectDetailsOrderNr"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_span="1"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned"
                    android:padding="3dip" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

the method `fillEditTexts`:

```
  private void fillEditTexts(final View view){
        final Project project = this.getShownProject();
        final EditText projectDescription = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsProjectDescription);

        final TextView projectNumber = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsProjectNr);
        final EditText bookingNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsBookingNr);
        final EditText orderNumber = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsOrderNr);
        if(project!=null){
            projectDescription.setText(project.getProjectDescription() == null ? " ": project.getProjectDescription());
            if(project.getProjectNumber()!=null){
                projectNumber.setText(project.getProjectNumber().toString());
            }
            if(project.getBookingNumber()!=null){
                bookingNumber.setText(project.getBookingNumber().toString());
            }
            if(project.getOrderNumber()!=null){
                orderNumber.setText(project.getOrderNumber().toString());
            }
        }

        final Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsButton_cancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProjectDetailsFragment.this.goBack();
            }
        });

        final Button save = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.projectDetailsButton_save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ProjectDetailsFragment.this.saveChanges(view);
                ProjectDetailsFragment.this.goBack();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: did you implement the `Fragment` lifecycle methods correctly? more specifically... did you inflate your layout correctly in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand... the keyboard pops up but when you try and type something the button gets focus?

Comment: @Alex: the edit fragments onCreateView() is called and looks like `@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.project_details1, container, false);
        this.fillEditTexts(view);
        return view;
    }`

Comment: @Alex (second comment). Until now I don't work with a popup keyboard. I work with an emulator and just use my real keyboard. The edit text is focused and when I try to type something, the button gets focused.

Comment: can you post the code for your `fillEditTexts()` method as well as the XML code in `res/layout/project_details1`? maybe post it as an edit in your question rather than in the comments so others can help too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all... I don't think your layout will end up displaying what you want it to display. It looks like you want your layout to contain a `LinearLayout` displaying the buttons and a `ScrollView` displaying a table, correct? If this is the case you should use a `LinearLayout` (with `android:orientation="vertical"`. Then make sure you order the children views the way you want them to appear; if you want the buttons to be displayed below the `ScrollView`, then copy and paste the `LinearLayout` that holds the Buttons to the bottom of the file. It should look something like this,

```
<LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView>
        <!-- display the grid -->
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- display the two buttons side by side -->
    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll have to get rid of the following attributes in your `ScrollView` if you do end up switching to a `LinearLayout` (as they are not supported by the class): `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_above="@id/projectDetailsButtons"`.

You should also be wary of the `android:layout_weight` attribute. In general, you want to try to avoid using nested weights, since calculating these weights inefficient and slows down the process of drawing the views on your screen. For example, you don't need the `layout_weight="2"` attribute for any of the buttons, as this information is redundant--deleting both of the weight attributes will have the weights default to "0", which should have the same effect.

That being said, I'm couldn't be sure if making these changes will fix your problem unless I saw more of your code, but it's definitely a step in the right direction. If I were to guess what the problem was, I'd say that your `Fragment` isn't able to inflate the layout correctly in `onCreateView()` because your XML file is littered with nested layouts that don't really display their views the way you want them to. Try making some changes and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Replacing the 'RelativeLayout' by a 'LinearLayout' resolved the problem.

Comment: watch out for those layout weights in the future :). glad to hear you got it up and running!